# parsing error - syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR

Tags: php, error-handling

**I have this line in PHP:**

```
$bom != b"\xEF\xBB\xBF"
```

When I run it, I get the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR in
C:\xampp\htdocs\MediaAlbumWeb\Utils\Utils.php on line 218
```

What is the T_NS_SEPARATOR in php and why is it unexpected?

Comment: That line has no parse errors. Paste your entire code if possible or atleast few lines before line 218.

Comment: please show some more code relevant to this.

Comment: just a wild guess: try removing the `b` before the string. the error message hints at namespaces though

Comment: @codaddict Actually, there is a parse error: it's the b, which PHP sees as a constant, followed by a string. The only that'd ever work if there was a concatenation in between ('.'). Nonetheless, I just think the "b" should be left out altogether.

Comment: @Berry: http://www.ideone.com/jf7Ij

Comment: @codaddict, what the... I've never seen this before, but I just tested it on my machine and it actually seems to work. Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: You have likely something like `\"` more up so that `"` is closing the string and \ is the unexpected `T_NS_SEPARATOR`. - x-ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751994/parse-error-issue-which-i-cant-solve ; del-ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454797/t-ns-separator-error-in-php

Comment: The `b''` syntax is available since PHP 5.2.1...

Answer (score 7):

You likely have an unclosed single or double quote above that line in your code.

What is the `b` that's outside of the quotes?

If it's a comparison, it could be something like:

```
if($bom != "b\xEF\xBB\xBF")
{
 //code
}
```

**Simple code to reproduce this error in PHP:**

```
<?php
$arg = "'T';                      //this unclosed double quote is perfectly fine.

$vehicle = ( $arg == 'B' ? 'bus' : 'not a bus');

print $vehicle . "\n";            //error is thrown on this line.  

?>
```

Run this, it prints an error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR in 
/var/www/sandbox/eric/code/php/run08/a.php on line 6
```

Comment: // determine if the file has a utf-8 bom and skip it if it does
            $bom = fread($fp, 3);
            if ($bom != b"\xEF\xBB\xBF")
                rewind($fp);

Answer (score 0):

You do a lot of Python, by any chance? b"string" is not a valid way to write your string in PHP, though it is in Python. If you just want the bytes, then you can write the string out as:

```
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
```

That works. If you want to check for inequality:

```
if( $bom != "\xEF\xBB\xBF" ) {
}
```

What are you checking for anyway? For a Byte Order Mark? And if so: why, exactly?

Comment: My bad: it seems b"\xEF\xBB\xBF"; is valid syntax in PHP, although I've never known this.

Comment: It is checking for bom utf format or not. How can I solve this?

Comment: Riaz; it seems that the syntax *is* correct. Would you mind showing the rest of the code, there seems to be an issue with that.

Comment: // determine if the file has a utf-8 bom and skip it if it does
            $bom = fread($fp, 3);
            if ($bom != b"\xEF\xBB\xBF")
                rewind($fp);