# Parse error issue which i can't solve

Tags: php

I don't know what's wrong with my code.
There is an error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR, expecting T_STRING in /home/&&&&/public_html/oscommerce/admin/modules.php(313) : eval()'d code on line 1`

This is the `Line 313`

```
eval('$keys .= ' . $value['set_function'] . "'" . $value['value'] . "', '" . $key . "');");
```

Values:

`$value['set_function']` contains `tep_cfg_select_option(array('Live', 'Sandbox'),`

`$value['value']` contains `Live`

`$key` contains `CONFIGURATION_PAYPAL`

Comment: the problem is, that your string is not properly ended/escaped. could be that you forgot a "(" after the [set_function] array)... but because I dont know whats inside those variables i dont have a clue

Comment: We need to know what `$value` and `$key` contain. Also, why are you using `eval()`? It is rare that you actually need to use it, and when you use it it almost always causes problems.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure you want to use eval()?

PHP documentation for 
[eval()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) says

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: Yes.. I do some precautions before eval.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the parenthesis don't seem to match.  You have 2 ) at the end while you only have one ( .

Comment: but the ( could be in `$value['set_function']`

Answer (score 0):

> eval('$keys .= ' . $value['set_function'] . "'" . $value['value'] . "', '" . $key . "');");

Will give you something like

```
$keys .= set_function'value', 'key');
```

That's not correct I believe.

How about adding `(` after `$value['set_function'] . "` ? You haven't opened the bracket after name of the function.

Another thing is that T_NS_SEPARATOR error means that you have `\` somewhere where it shouldn't be. Per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6454891/2028547 - see the values of all your variables for weird characters.

Comment: but the ( could be in `$value['set_function']`

Comment: I doubt anyone is stupid enough to store bracket with a function name under a variable called "set_function" (no offence).

Comment: You never know - considering the error that he's receiving (NS_SEPERATOR) it looks like the error is actually something to do with bad escaping.

Comment: Ok, so basically two things to do: Get rid of brackets from variable storing function name (as it should store ONLY function name) and then look into special characters, especially backslash.

Comment: I found it out.. after echoing `$value['set_function']` it displays slashes yet there is no slashes on value itself..

Comment: @Ken - try running this regular expression on your `$value['set_function']` http://stackoverflow.com/a/6073257/2028547

Answer (score 0):

Looks like whatever is in `$value['set_function']` or `$value['value']` or `$key` have  a `\` in 
them

Try echoing what's in `eval()` rather than running `eval()` - this will let you see the code PHP is trying to run.

The error is basically saying that there's a namespace seperator (`\`) in a strange place within the `eval()`'d code